# Get MySQL results based on order of ID's in a variable

Tags: php, mysql

I have a PHP variable that holds a JSON string like this below, each number is the `id` from the `module_category`MySQL table

```
$json_order = '["8","2","7","3","1","6","4","5"]';
```

So using the `$json_order` I need to iterate the table below, but return the results in the Order that `$json_order` is in.

```
SELECT id, name
FROM  `module_category`
```

Can anyone show me a good way of doing this?

Comment: In the `$json_order` all these are `id` in `module_category`?

Comment: @RohanKumar Yes that's correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use FIELD as follows:

```
$order = trim('["8","2","7","3","1","6","4","5"]', '[]');

$query = "SELECT id, name FROM  `module_category`
          ORDER BY IF (FIELD(id, $order), 0, id), FIELD(id, $order)";
```

Note, that it's important to use IF in this case otherwise `FIELD` will return `0` for all the results which are not in the list making them appear in the top. We just invert this behaviour: now for each row whose id is within the list we return `0` - this makes these rows topmost, then they are sorted by `id`.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I have tried it out and with the IF() being used it returns the result in the order `1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8` instead of `8,2,7,3,1,6,4,5`

Comment: UPD: This seems to work for me when I test. Let me know. However query becomes strange, maybe I'm missing something obvious.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [**FIELD()**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_field) function, which is used for custom ordering, just what you need, you can use it like this:

```
//Convert $json_order into '8','2','7','3','1','6','4','5' to insert it in sql
$order = str_replace(array('"','[',']'), array("'",'',''), $json_order);
$sql = 'SELECT id, name
FROM  `module_category` ORDER BY FIELD(id, '.$order.' )';
```

**UPDATE:** Sorry there was an error in my above code, it's now corrected :-)

Answer (score 2):

Take the list of IDs and sculpt the following

```
SELECT id,name FROM `module_category` ORDER BY
FIELD(id,8,2,7,3,1,6,4,5);
```

The [FIELD function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_field) returns the index position of each value. You use that to order by.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my solution;

```
        $json_order = '["8","2","7","3","1","6","4","5"]';
        $decoded = json_decode($json_order);
        echo 'SELECT id, name FROM `table` WHERE `id` IN ('.implode(',', $decoded).') ORDER BY FIELD(id,'.implode(',', $decoded).');';
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$json_order = '["8","2","7","3","1","6","4","5"]';
$a=json_decode($json_order,"true");
$sql="SELECT id, name
FROM  `module_category`
ORDER BY FIELD (id,".implode(",",$a).")";
```

So basically you take the JSON, convert it into an array and then implode it to be comma separated. Then using the Field operation of SQl you can fetch everything in order.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$sql=SELECT id, name FROM  `module_category`
 ORDER BY FIELD(id, 8,2,7,3,1,6,4,5), json_order;
```

Read http://www.electrictoolbox.com/mysql-order-specific-field-values/
and http://lists.mysql.com/mysql/209784